# How can i javascript in mustasche

Tags: javascript, mustache

I want to use javascript inside the mustache template. (test.mustache)

https://test.com/?lang=en

```
<script>
let query = window.location.search;
console.log(query);
</script>
```

I got ?lang=en with the above code.

```
{{#cats}}
<a href="{{link}}" class="ui label-lsc" style="background-color: {{wpsc_cat_bg_color}}; color: {{wpsc_cat_color}};">{{{value}}}</a>
{{/cats}}
```

i in this code
I want to append ?lang=en after {{link}}.

Is there any way?

Comment: You can't affect the mustache template from code generated by the mustache template. It's too late. You can [modify the generated DOM as usual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use JavaScript in your template.

The entire point of the template is to allow code to be extracted. Whatever code is currently executing your template is feeding the template a `link` variable, which the template is outputting via `{{link}}`. You need to modify that calling code so that it alters the value of `link` before it's passed to the template.